# How to mantain radiobutton, dropdown and checkbox values if submit fails PHP

Tags: php

I know how to it with text inputs. I can easily put a php script in its value, but doing it with input groups seems different. How can I mantain the values of group inputs if the submission of the form fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-mark a checkbox or radio button as checked, you use this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="foo" checked="checked"/>
```

The key is `checked="checked"`.

If you are using groups of checkboxes, make sure the `name` of the field ends with brackets `[]`, like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" id="foo_1" value="1" checked="checked"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" id="foo_2" value="2" checked="checked"/>
```

Then your `$_REQUEST['foo']` variable will automatically be an array of checked values.  You can use `in_array` to see if a particular checkbox was checked.

**Update based on comment**

Here's how I would set it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" id="foo_1" value="1" <?= (isset($_POST['foo'] && in_array('1', $_POST['foo'])) ? 'check="checked"' : '' ?>/>
```

For single items (like radios), use this:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo" value="1" <?= isset($_POST['radio]) ? 'check="checked"' : '' ?>/>
```

Hope that helps.

**Update 2:**
Also, ***make sure you escape user input!*** Your example *should* look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username']) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);?>">
```

Always assume the user is trying to hack your system, always escape user input!

Comment: I'm using this for text inputs.<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username']) echo $_POST['username'];?>">

So how to do it exactly with checkboxes, radiobutton and dropdowns?

Comment: What if I have two radio buttons like gender, male or female selection. I believe that checked = "checked" would contain true or false but where exactly does the checked value came from? I don't know how it would contain true or false. I'm a newbie.

Comment: `check="checked" means check *that* input.  There's no true or false, you just don't print the `checked="checked"` value if the checkbox or radio button is not checked or selected by default.  [More Info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Comment: Oh. I get it. I thought that echoing checked is enough. But I tried to use checked only and works fine too. I used this to get values of a radiobuttons
    <?php if(isset ($_POST["gender"])) { if($_POST["gender"] == "Male"){ echo "checked"; }} ?>

Answer (score 0):

Print the `" checked"` attribute for radio buttons and checkbox `input` tags, or the `" selected"` attribute for dropdown `option` tags.

Comment: I'm using this for text inputs.<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username']) echo $_POST['username'];?>"> So how to do it exactly with checkboxes, radiobutton and dropdowns?